# Aceitar valor null

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou montando um código SELECT para retornar o endereço completo que está no banco de dados, porém caso exista algum valor 'null' em alguma coluna ele me retorna o SELECT inteiro 'null'. Como eu poderia fazer a coluna com o 'null' ser impressa também ou fazer a verificação ignorar apenas o valor 'null' (por exemplo deixando em branco)?

```
SELECT (estado+'-'+paisAcronimo+' | '+cidade+' — '+bairro+', '+rua+', '+CAST(numero AS varchar(5))) Endereço'
FROM endereco
```

Não posso só pular a linha caso haja algum valor nulo, como aconteceria usando 'IS NOT NULL' e caso use 'IS NULL' ele me retorna apenas 'null'

Exemplo:

Quando todas as colunas estão **preenchidas**:

- Rio de Janeiro-BR | Nova Iguaçu — Cabuçu, R. Maranguape, S/N

Quando há alguma coluna **vazia**:

- *NULL*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver é utilizando as funções [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) e [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) fornecidas pelo banco de dados.

Segue um exemplo de como utilizar:

```
SELECT CONCAT(COALESCE(estado,''),' - ',COALESCE(paisAcronimo,''),' | ',COALESCE(cidade,''),' - ',COALESCE(bairro,''),', ',COALESCE(rua,''),', ',COALESCE(numero,'S/N')) Endereço
FROM endereco
```

#### Explicando o código

A função `CONCAT` retorna a string resultante da concatenação dos argumentos, caso exista mais de um argumento. Se for do tipo numérico é feito um cast para `string` do seu valor.

Caso algum dos argumentos seja `NULL` a função retorna `NULL`

Ex:

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('My', 'S', 'QL');
        -> 'MySQL'
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('My', NULL, 'QL');
        -> NULL
```

---

A função `COALESCE` retorna o primeiro argumento não-nulo da lista de argumentos ou NULL caso não existam valores diferentes de nulo.

Ex:

```
mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL,'S/N')
       -> S/N
```

Comment: Opa, resolveu perfeitamente meu problema. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar o operador IS NULL ou IS NOT NULL

```
SELECT (estado+'-'+paisAcronimo+' | '+cidade+' — '+bairro+', '+rua+', '+CAST(numero AS varchar(5))) Endereço' FROM endereco WHERE nome_da_Coluna IS NULL
```

Comment: Tentei fazer isso, porém ele continua me retornando 'NULL' no SELECT. No caso como são várias colunas, usei o operador OR e ele me retornou apenas aquelas que tinham alguma coluna vazia e quando usei AND ele não me retornou nada pois na tabela não existe nenhuma linha com todas as colunas vazias